# Cannot Add Friends to Business Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I created a page for my condo community and am trying to add friends but there is no option for this. I created it as a local business and edited it accordingly, have pressed ALL the possible tabs, but no luck. Plus, when I search for the page through another FBook profile, it cannot be found. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Businesses can't add friends because that's how Pages work. You can only import a list of emails so that people get notified of the page. Facebook should be showing you the option to do so on the Getting Started tab.

Comment: Not true... I have the same problem as Lena Masson. I also cannot add friends. But, my fellow administrator can. I also cannot add friends anymore for my other pages, yet my fellow administrators can (same pages). I really don't understand what the problem is...